# Read values ​in an angular formbuilder

Tags: angular, formbuilder, form-control

Good morning,
After spending a few hours search the solution to read the values ​​contained in my Angular formbuilder, I ask for your help, here is my code:

```js
  formD: any;
  pForm= new FormGroup({ typeDePret: new FormControl(''), montantDuPret: new FormControl(''), tauxDuPret: new FormControl(''), dureeDuPret: new FormControl(''), dontDiffere: new FormControl(''), });
  profileForm: FormGroup;
  aliases: any;

  
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      credit: this.fb.group({
        typeDePret: [''],
        montantDuPret: [''],
        tauxDuPret: [''],
        dureeDuPret: [''],
        dontDiffere: ['']
      }),
      aliases: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
  }
  
 
   // Define a method to submit the form data to Firebase
submitForm() {
  // Retrieve the form data using the FormGroup's `value` property
  this.formD = this.pForm.value && this.aliases.value;
  
  // Use AngularFireDatabase to save the form data to Firebase
  this.db.list('form-data').push(this.formD);
  console.log(this.formD);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<form [formGroup]="profileForm"class="needs-validation" novalidate>

            <label for="montantDuPret-{{i}}">Montant du prêt</label><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input id="montantDuPret-{{i}}" type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"formControlName="montantDuPret" id="montantDuPret">
              <span class="input-group-text">.00 €</span></div>
              <div *ngIf="aliasArray.at(i).invalid && aliasArray.at(i).touched">
                <div class="error2" *ngIf="aliasArray.at(i).hasError('required')">
         Svp entrer le montant de votre pret.
      </div>
    </div>

    
                              etc...
      </form>
```

I tried to read my data in console log before sending it to firebase but no value appears..

Comment: The code example you have given in Angular 2+ but you are adding angular.min.js library. Angular and angular js not same.

Comment: thank you for your feedback I now manage to see my form group in my console log but my values ​​are still empty while information is completed in the form. How should I proceed to display the values ​​contained in my various form-controls?